# Toggle Native Events Capability of WebDriver at run time

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, native, selenium-webdriver

Mouse Actions like Hover-over an element using 'Action Builder' does not seem to be reliable while running on Internet Explorer, when 'Native Events' is enabled. (Chrome and Firefox works perfectly)

On disabling the 'Native Events' using the below code, the Mouse Actions like Hover-over an element starts working as expected in Internet Explorer also. But lot other things stop working (like clicking a button), when the 'Native Events' is disabled.

```
Capabilities.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:5556/wd/hub"), Capabilities);
```

Hence, is it possible to toggle the 'Native Events' setting of a WebDriver at run-time as below?

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:5556/wd/hub"), Capabilities);
.
.
driver.setCapability("nativeEvents", false);
Perform Hover-over operations
driver.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
Perform other operations
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the capabilities you give the WebDriver are set for the life of that instance.

Therefore, you cannot change them when you feel like it.

Comment: Damn :( ... So now I have to split my tests into two parts - "desktop" and "mobile" ... :(